# Access data from SharedPreferences at boot time

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, togglebutton

I want to  start service at boot time. Its working fine.I now i want to start service only if toggle button is on.I am saving state of toggle button state in  SharedPreferences.

PROBLEM
I am getting default value from SharedPreferences that is false in my case

CODE of BroadcastReceiver is as follows

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {




         SharedPreferences saved_values=context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences( "ServiceLockTest", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         boolean checkstate = saved_values.getBoolean("tgpref", false); // return false
         int pr=saved_values.getInt("progess", 100); //return 100

         TheService.SHAKE_THRESHOLD=pr;

         if(checkstate)
         {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, TheService.class);
         context.startService(myIntent);
         }
         else
         {
             Toast.makeText(context,"yoooooooooooooooooooooo" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              System.out.println(pr);
              System.out.println(checkstate);
         }


    } 
}
```

code of saving state of toggle button

```
if (isChecked) {


                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true); // value to store
                    editor.commit();
                    // The toggle is enabled
                     if (mgr.isAdminActive(cn))
                     {
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Service is afor",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                     }
                     else
                     {
                         Log.i("Admin", "Not an admin");//mean admin is not active
                         showAct();//will open new activity
                     }
                }
```

Please help.thanks

Comment: Are you saving toggle button's state off?

Comment: as i said it giving me default value even i am saving on state i.e toggle is on and i reboot the phone still its false after reboot